# Filter rows in a group based on the value for another group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table of data which includes, among others, an ID, a (somehow sorted) grouping column and a date. For each ID, based on the minimum value of the date for a given group, I would like to filter out the rows of another given group that occurred after that date.

I thought about using `pivot_wider` and `pivot_longer`, but I was not able to operate on columns containing list values and single values simultaneously.

How can I do it efficiently (using any `tidyverse` method, if possible)?

For instance, given

```
library(dplyr)
tbl <- tibble(id = c(rep(1,5), rep(2,5)),
              type = c("A","A","A","B","C","A","A","B","B","C"),
              dat = as.Date("2021-12-07") - c(3,0,1,2,0,3,6,2,4,3))

# A tibble: 10 × 3
#       id type  dat       
#    <int> <chr> <date>    
#  1     1 A     2021-12-04
#  2     1 A     2021-12-07
#  3     1 A     2021-12-06
#  4     1 B     2021-12-05
#  5     1 C     2021-12-07
#  6     2 A     2021-12-04
#  7     2 A     2021-12-01
#  8     2 B     2021-12-05
#  9     2 B     2021-12-03
# 10     2 C     2021-12-04
```

I would like the following result, where I discarded A-typed elements that occurred after the first of the B-typed ones, but none of the C-typed ones:

```
# A tibble: 7 × 3
#      id type  dat       
#   <int> <chr> <date>    
# 1     1 A     2021-12-04
# 2     1 B     2021-12-05
# 3     1 C     2021-12-07
# 4     2 A     2021-12-01
# 5     2 B     2021-12-05
# 6     2 B     2021-12-03
# 7     2 C     2021-12-04
```

Comment: I assume that the C type's date is 2021-12-07 ?

Comment: Yes, that was a copy-paste error. Thanks

Comment: How good does your example represents your real use case? I.e. is your type always A/B/C = letters? Are youvonly interested in filtering type A vs B or could there also be cases where you filter B vs C or A vs C? Please clarify.

Comment: The example is a bit abstract. In my particular case, `type` is kind of a sorted set of events (buy < cook < eat or search < select < buy, for instance). So I am also interested in doing the same for "B" and "C" also. Doing both filters at the same time would be perfect, but I do not mind doing both separetely.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use pivot_wider aand pivot_longer in this case. It does the trick, but maybe you are looking for something shorter.

```
tbl <- tibble(id = 1:5, type = c("A","A","A","B","C"), dat = as.Date("2021-12-07") - c(3,4,1,2,0)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = dat) %>% 
  filter(A < min(B, na.rm = TRUE) | is.na(A)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(2:4, names_to = "type", values_to = "dat") %>% 
  na.omit()

# A tibble: 4 × 3
     id type  dat       
  <int> <chr> <date>    
1     1 A     2021-12-04
2     2 A     2021-12-03
3     4 B     2021-12-05
4     5 C     2021-12-07
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. However, by checking your solution I realized that I made a mistake in my example (please, check it again, if possible). The ID is not unique within the column, so your widening process would produce duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way using kind of SQL logic :

```
tbl_to_delete <- tbl %>% dplyr::filter(type == "A" & dat > min(tbl$dat[tbl$type=="B"]))
tbl2 <- tbl %>% dplyr::anti_join(tbl_to_delete,by=c("type","dat"))
```

First you isolate the rows you want to delete, then you discard them from your original data.

You can of course merge the two lines before into one for better code management :

```
tbl %>% anti_join(tbl %>% filter(type == "A" & dat > min(tbl$dat[tbl$type=="B"])),by=c("type","dat"))
```

Or if you really hate rbase :

```
tbl %>% anti_join(tbl %>% filter(type == "A" & dat > tbl %>% filter(type == "B") %>% pull(dat) %>% min()),by=c("type","dat"))
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not clear enough in my question. I meant the minimum PER ID, not the global minimum. But your `anti_join` idea (first time I heard about that method, thanks!) gave me a path to follow.

Comment: Then just add a "group_by(id)" an then (probably) delete the "type == "B"" from the condition, then I think you will have what you want